# How do I get these javascript card graphics to display correctly on wordpress? (with examples)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, graphics

Having trouble getting the card graphics from this page: https://www.micski.dk/2023/01/18/how-to-show-playing-cards-in-wordpress/

To display correctly on this page: https://spectrefaxpoker.com/2023/04/23/test-post/

Using the supplied code, I'm having trouble with the graphics displaying vertically instead of horizontally.

Tried changing the theme but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this in the CSS for your svg images:

```
svg, img, embed, object {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

You can use `display: inline-block` instead to have them align horizontally.